# Measure Theoretic Definition of Joint Probability Density

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be random variables on a shared probability space $(\Omega,\Sigma, \mu)$. The joint distribution of these variables is a measure $\mu_{X_1,\dots,X_n}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that for all bounded measurable functions $f_1,\dots,f_n$

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[f_1(X_1)\dots f_n(X_n)\right] = \int f_1\dots f_n\, d\mu_{X_1,\dots,X_n}
$$

I am not sure what motivates this definition and not sure how to make sense of it. All I see is this relation states that the average over $\mathbb{R}^n$ equals the average over the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^n$, for all bounded measurable functions, but I don't know how this defines a measure (a function that assigns size to measurable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: I don't see any average over the diagonal in $\mathbb R^n$ here.

Comment: @AndreasBlass What makes me think of the average over the diagonal is left side $\int f_1(X_1(\omega))\dots f_n(X_n(\omega))\, d\mu(\omega)$. Am I missing something? Anyway I am not sure how this relation gives a natural definition of joint density.

Comment: That's not a diagonal. I'm not *exactly* sure what you're seeing that gives that impression, so this is just a guess. But each function $f_k$ being applied to the random variable $X_k$—the $X_k$ still collectively span the entire $\mathbb{R}^n$, or at least the supported part of it.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of the diagonal in $\Omega^n$?

Answer (score 1):

The goal of your definition is to uniquely describe a measure $\mu_X$ on $\mathbb R^n$, that gives the joint distribution of the variables $X_1, \dots, X_n$. Note we may not already have such a measure;  $\mu$ is a measure on $\Omega$, which can be a completely different space.

A natural way to define the measure $\mu_X$ is to take

$$\mu_X(A) = \mu(\{X \in A\}) = \mathbb E_\mu[1_A(X)]\tag{1}.$$

You can prove that this indeed describes a measure, and that it satisfies the condition you gave above.

Conversely, for any measurable sets $A_1, \dots, A_n$, your condition implies

$$\mu_X(A_1 \times \dots \times A_n) = \mathbb E_\mu[1_{A_1}(X_1)\dots1_{A_n}(X_n)]\tag{2}.$$

The cylinder sets $A_1 \times \dots \times A_n$ are a $\pi$-system generating the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^n$, so by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem, any measure satisfying $(2)$ must be equal to $(1)$.

We thus have that your definition is equivalent to the definition $(1)$. Personally I'd find $(1)$ easier to understand, but logically they're the same.

Comment: Detail: a measure on the Borel sets, not on the whole set $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Yes, it's shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$, $Y$ are random variables defined on a same space $\Omega(\Gamma) $ with probability $P_\Omega $ , these variables determine in $R$
(or in spaces $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2 $ , in general) individual probabilities $P_X$ and $P_Y$ respectively. We can define on $R^2$ (or in $\Omega_1 \times \Omega_2$) a joint probability given by:
$$P_{X\circ Y}(A \times B)=P_\Omega (X\in A\cap Y\in B)=P_\Omega ((X\times Y)\in A\times B)$$
where the marginal probabilities agree with $P_X$ and $P_Y$. The probability is certainly concentrated on the diagonal:
$$\int f(x,y)dP_{X\circ Y}=\int f(X(\omega) ,Y(\omega))dP_{\sigma(X,Y)}$$

Comment: It is not sufficient to define a function on the 'rectangles' $A\times B$.

Comment: Of course. It is easy to verify that this function is $\sigma$-additive over the rectangles and therefore can be extended in a unique way to the $\sigma$-algebra generated by them, the Borel sets.